# Backbone: how to listen events on el container

Tags: events, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm wondering how to listen a simple event (hover or out) on the main ".list" element container.

I tried this at the View but it doesn't work.

```
template:"#sortingTemplate"
tagName:"div"
className:"list"
events:
  "hover"         : "hoverContainer"
  "out"           : "outContainer"
  "hover .list"   : "hoverContainer"
  "out .list"     : "outContainer"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: try using `"mouseover"` instead of `"hover"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two should do what you need:

```
  "hover"         : "hoverContainer"
  "out"           : "outContainer"
```

They are essentially saying 'bind to my top-level el'. The bottom two are saying 'bind to a child element within my el with a class of list'.

**EDIT**

Also as @Vic pointed out (and I didn't notice), you are using incorrect DOM events :D. As he suggests change them to `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
  "mouseover"         : "hoverContainer"
  "mouseout"          : "outContainer"
```

Comment: ok, tried it. now it triggers the event "mousehover", but if the mouse go over an element inside the main container, it triggers the "mouseout" event.

Comment: @SashaGrey use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). jQuery normalizes these across browsers.

Comment: @kalley: thank you!
(your is the correct answer for me. if you write it from scratch you have my green check)